# ssh into host and running service check script

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I need to ssh and perform service check on multiple hosts

say List of hosts:
host1
host2
host3

I wrote the script as follows but it is getting stuck at ssh only

```
#!/bin/bash

service=splunk

for host in $(</tmp/tstuf.txt);
do
  ssh $host;
  if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
  then
    echo "$service is running"
  else
    echo "$service is not running"
  fi
done
```

while running the script it is running ssh and going on to host1 from current host and stuck there.. It is not running service check. Can someone please suggest

Comment: **Not** an aswer, just another way to do what you want to do: try [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), is very useful and I think that fit for your needs. This information help me a lot! >>> [How Ansible work](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works)

Comment: why not just `for host in ${hosts[@]}; do ssh $host service splunk status; done`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Will it show me the status on screen?

Comment: Yes, just as though you had executed `ssh hostname service splunk status` for each host by hand, one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is "getting stuck at ssh only" because you are not giving it a command to execute. The `ssh $host` just establishes an interactive ssh session with `$host`, which then waits for you to start interacting with it.

When you `exit` from the remote host, your script will continue and run `if (( $(ps ....) > 0 )); then .......... fi` on your LOCAL system.  And then continue the for loop with the next host in the list (getting "stuck" again until you exit).

```
#!/bin/bash

service=splunk

for host in $(</tmp/tstuf.txt); do
  ssh $host "if (( \$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 )); then
               echo $service is running
             else
               echo $service is not running
             fi"
done
```

or, as @DopeGhoti suggested, a much simpler, better alternative is:

```
#!/bin/sh

service=splunk

for host in $(</tmp/tstuf.txt); do
  # echo -n "$host:"  # optional. uncomment the echo if wanted.
  ssh "$host" service "$service" status
done
```

---

An even better alternative is to install something like LLNL's Parallel Distributed Shell aka [pdsh](https://github.com/chaos/pdsh), then (after configuring the hosts list file in `/etc/genders`) you can just run commands like:

```
pdsh -g all service splunk status
```

that runs `service splunk status` on the group of hosts defined by the "all" tag.

`pdsh` runs the commands on multiple hosts at the same time (hence the name "parallel distributed shell"), rather than one at a time.  Each line of output from the remote system is prefixed by its hostname.

e.g. on my own small home network:

```
$ pdsh -g all uptime
kali:  12:09:03 up 3 days, 23:26,  2 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.05, 0.06
hanuman:  12:09:03 up 12 days, 13:09,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
indra:  12:09:03 up 12 days, 13:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.07, 0.12, 0.09
ganesh:  12:09:03 up 34 days, 23:34, 19 users,  load average: 1.86, 1.48, 1.40
```

BTW, single-line output like the `uptime` example above can be formatted into neat columns by piping into, e.g., `column -t`.  multi-line output can be grouped by hostname by piping into `pdsh`'s companion utility `dshbak`.

If you don't want to be entering passwords all the time, it requires ssh key-based authentication to be set up on each remote host...as would your for loop or anything else that connects via ssh.

`pdsh` is packaged for debian, and most other linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Inner loop in a single line.
the return status of 'pgrep' is returned by ssh to the local host.

```
echo "$host: $service is $(ssh $host pgrep $service >/dev/null || echo "NOT ")running"
```